# flot bar chart ticks not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, bar-chart

my data:

```
var data5 = [
    { label: "my cat",  data: [[1,10], [4,20], [7,30]], color: 'rgb(85, 96, 42)'},
    { label: "my job",  data: [[2,30], [5,20], [8,30]], color: '#42215F'}
];
```

my options:

```
var type = {};
type[charttype] = {show: true};
type["xaxis"] = {ticks: [[1,"foo"], [2,"bar"], [4,"cat"], [5,"woo"], [7,"cookie"], [8,"yay"]]};

var chart_options = {};
chart_options["series"] = type;
```

however, when I

```
var plot = $.plot($(div), data5, chart_options);
```

The ticks just show up as 1-9, instead of with the strings I've given.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data5 = [
    { label: "my cat",  data: [[1,10], [4,20], [7,30]], color: 'rgb(85, 96, 42)'},
    { label: "my job",  data: [[2,30], [5,20], [8,30]], color: '#42215F'}
];

var chart_options = {
    series: {lines:{show: true}},
    xaxis:{ticks: [[1,"foo"], [2,"bar"],  [4,"cat"], [5,"woo"],  [7,"cookie"], [8,"yay"] ]}
};

var plot = $.plot($('div'), data5, chart_options);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hUs6h/)

`charttype` is replaced with an actual type (lines/points..)

`xaxis` should not be inside of `series` object, instead on the same level.

Comment: That did work... so something must be wrong with my formatting. I need to be able to keep it in the format I have it-- can you see what the error is?

Comment: Here is your version (with just the errors fixed): http://jsfiddle.net/fSLth/ , hope that helps